# Sharepoint rest api - Create field and add to all content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

i am able to create a new field in a sharepoint list using the "createfieldasxml" method of "fields" endpoint.
There is a way to add this field to all content type, and not just to the default content type?
The other way i thought is to add manually every field i need to all the content type, but it's not the best solution. I did not find in the documentation that parameter, but it is present in the csom approach.

Thanks

Comment: Does this link help - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158224/creating-site-column-and-add-it-to-content-type

Comment: Unfortunately no, because this is the csom approach that i can't use

Comment: Add a content type field reference to collection - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245869(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN . Don't miss the limitations towards the end of the article.

Comment: Yes, i know that i can do this way. Since i need to do this for 20 fields,  I asked if there's a way to do in a single call when i create these fields, like in the  interface where there is a "add to all content type" box

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered you question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/541651/sharepoint-rest-api-create-field-and-add-to-all-co.html

> You could set the Options property to 4(AddToAllContentTypes) in the
> body using createfieldasxml method like the below:
>
> ```
>  {
>    "parameters": {
>      "__metadata": {
>        "type": "SP.XmlSchemaFieldCreationInformation"
>      },
>      "SchemaXml": "<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='test' Name='test'></Field>",
>      "Options":4
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> The AddFieldOptions value can be found here:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee542202(v=office.15)